# I want to run two separate loops in parallel using openmp

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

The two different loops should run in parallel in C using openmp. I am new to openmp and have found solutions where steps of a single loop are run in parallel and not multiple loops . please could someone suggest how to go about it.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() 
{
      // this loop must run on processor 1
      for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
      {   // work to be done in loop1
      }

      //this loop must run on processor 2
      for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
      {   //work to be done in loop2
      }
}
```

Comment: What is preventing you to do the work of loop2 in loop1?

Comment: It is just the way i have decomposed the two independent tasks so that they can be run in parallel

Comment: I would advice you to first learn how to use the tool (openmp) and then adjust your code to that tool rather than making assumptions of the tool and adjusting your code to those assumptions. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this, but read the **warning** below.

```
int id;

#pragma omp parallel private(id) num_threads(2)
{
    id = omp_get_thread_num();
    if(id == 0) {
        // Loop1
    }

    else if(id == 1) {
        // Loop2
    }
}
```

Pretty self explanatory. Create two threads, get the id of the thread that is executing and select what to do depending on the id.

However, this is a pretty awkward way of doing it. It's not how you usually parallelize stuff with OpenMP. This is more or Pthreads style.

### Warning

Remember that `num_threads(2)` does not guarantee you two threads. So if you want to use this method, you need some kind of guard.

```
if(omp_get_num_threads() < 2) {
    // Serial code
} else {
    // Parallel code
}
```

And suddenly, everything becomes pretty clunky.